# jQuery Slider - full width - opening itself from the midddle

Tags: jquery, animation, slider, width

I have to do that :

[image]

How would you do it ? Would you use a jQuery plugin ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Well, attach click events to hide/show the content layers, load content using AJAX etc.. It should be rather straight forward. Whats the code you've got already?

Comment: I only have the HTML/CSS files. I was wondering if there is something existing to "split" a page like that (cutting even the image on the left)

Comment: I only have the top left page

Comment: That would be difficult to achieve unless you've got the image in 2 parts, one that goes before the content area, and one that goes after.

Comment: yes, how can I make the grey div going out of the main wrap ? do I alhave to cut the wrap in 2 parts ?

Comment: Should be achievable without a plugin using the native `.slideDown()` or `.animate()` effect plus possibly something to keep everything centred.

Comment: Have your content div (initially `display: none`) and do a `slideDown()` on it when the trigger is clicked. `slideUp()` to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Happy,

The trickiest aspect of this is getting the HTML and CSS right. jQuery makes the javascript reasonably trivial.

Splitting of the image can be achieved by abutting two clipped instances of same image. The logic for this can be totally in the stylesheet but as the clipping arithmetic is tricky to work out, it's simpler to do it in javascript. Thus, the split can be adjusted by changing *one* value; if this value puts the split outside the image bounds, then the image will be wholly in the top-half or the bottom-half and will remain intact.

Here's a sample page - it's doesn't do everything you want but will get you started.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
#outerWrapper {
    width: 900px;
}
.half {
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid #000;
}
#topHalf {
    height: 250px;
}
#bottomHalf {
    height: 150px;
}
.leftColumn {
    width: 190px;
    float: left;
}
.content {
    width: 698px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border: 1px solid #909090;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#openers {
    font-family: monospace;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
}
.opener {
    font-family: monospace;
    width: 90px;
    color: #111;
}
.opener.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.splitImg {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
#centerWrapper {
    clear: both;
    display: none;
    width: 900px;
}
#hiddenMenus {
    display: none;
}
.centerSection {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url("http://www.teacherfiles.com/clipart/xbackgrounds/graph_paper.jpg");
    height: 100px;
}
.centerSection h3 {
    width: 810px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1px 12px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border: 4px double #99C;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-family: verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #006;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}
.centerSection .close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 13px;
    font-family: verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //The image is "split" by abutting two clipped instances of same image.
    //Splitting can be achieved in the stylesheet but the arithmetic is tricky 
    //so we do it in javascript. Just set `dims` to be compatible with the 
    //image (and width & height set in the HTML) and the rest will look after itself. 
    // *****
    var dims = {w:180, h:120, v:60};//image width(px), image height(px), vertical_split from top (px)
    // *****
    var rect_top    = [0,      dims.w, dims.v, 0];
    var rect_bottom = [dims.v, dims.w, dims.h, 0];
    var $t = $("#topImg").css({
        bottom: (dims.v - dims.h) + 'px',//this will be negative
        clip: 'rect(' + rect_top.join('px,') +'px)'
    }).show();
    var $b = $("#bottomImg").css({
        top: '-' + dims.v + 'px',//this will be negative
        clip: 'rect(' + rect_bottom.join('px,') +'px)'
    }).show();
    $b.attr({ src:$t.attr('src'), width:$t.width(), height:$t.height() });
});

$(function() {
    //Set button widths to allow dynamic bold style without jog
    var $openers = $(".opener").each(function(){
        var $o = $(this);
        $o.width((7 * (1 + $o.text().length)) + 'px');
    });
});

$(function() {
    //add close buttons to the menu sections
    $(".centerSection h3").each(function() {
        $('<button class="close">X</button>').insertBefore($(this));
    });
});

$(function() {
    //Open and close the centre menus section
    var $$ = {//jQuery object cache
        centerWrapper: $("#centerWrapper"),
        hiddenMenus: $("#hiddenMenus"),
        defaultMenu: $("#defaultMenu")
    };
    var $openers = $(".opener").on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this),
            $old = $$.centerWrapper.find(".centerSection"),
            $new = $($link.attr('rel')),
            speed = 1000,//'slow',
            open = function() {
                unload();
                $$.centerWrapper.append($new).slideDown(speed);
                $link.addClass('selected');
            },
            unload = function(){
                $old.appendTo($$.hiddenMenus);//unload
                $openers.removeClass('selected');
            };
        $new = (!$new.length) ? $$.defaultMenu : $new;
        $$.centerWrapper.stop();
        if( $old.length ) { //if a centerSection is currently loaded
            var fn = ( $new.get(0) == $old.get(0) ) ? unload : open;
            $$.centerWrapper.slideUp(speed, fn);//close then either unload or reopen 
        }
        else { open(); } //open from closed
    });
    function close(e) {
        $openers.filter(".selected").trigger('click');
    }
    $(".centerSection").on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }).on('click', '.close', close);
    $(document).on('click', close);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="outerWrapper">
    <div class="half" id="topHalf">
        <div class="leftColumn">
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <img class="splitImg" id="topImg" src="http://www.childrenshealthyfood.com/healthy-food-schools/pics/healthy-foods/fresh-fruit-and-vegetables.jpg" width="180" height="120" />
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Top Half</h2>
            <div id="openers">
                <!--a class="opener" href="#" rel="#cocktail">Cocktail Menu</a>
                <a class="opener" href="#" rel="#buffet">Buffet Menu</a-->
                <span>Menus:</span>
                <button class="opener" rel="#cocktailMenu">Cocktails</button>
                <button class="opener" rel="#buffetMenu">Buffet</button>
                <button class="opener" rel="#luncheonMenu">Luncheon</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="centerWrapper"></div>

    <div class="half" id="bottomHalf">
        <div class="leftColumn">
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <img class="splitImg" id="bottomImg" /><!-- src, width and height are set dynamically -->
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Bottom Half</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="hiddenMenus">
    <div class="centerSection" id="cocktailMenu">
        <h3>Cocktail Menu</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="centerSection" id="buffetMenu">
        <h3>Buffet Menu</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="centerSection" id="defaultMenu">
        <h3>Menu not found</h3>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f4JTf/1/show/)**

Tested in Opera 12.02 and IE9.

What's missing:

- "Clamshell" opening; would take more effort to achieve
- To close menus; There's a toggle action on the links; click anywhere outside the open menu; click the dynamically inserted [x] button at top right of each open menu.
- Image splitting logic applies to a single image in the left column; as the code stands, no other images will split.

**Doctype**: I tested locally with an XHTML doctype (as above) but everything works without modification in jsFiddle, so it seems to be fine under HTML5.

**jQuery**: 1.7.1+